# Supporting multiple OU using principalcontext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have been trying to get user by providing container

```
string domain = "mydomain.com.pk";
string container = "ou=dotnet,ou=qa,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=pk";

using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.0.150:389", container, domain + "\\salman.zafar", "password")) {
    string userPrincipalName = "user1" + "@" + domain;

    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = context.ValidateCredentials(userPrincipalName, "password");
    if (isValid) {
        UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userPrincipalName);
        Console.WriteLine(up.Enabled);
        Console.WriteLine(up.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(up.EmailAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(up.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Now hierarchy is like this

> mydomain.com.pk
>   dotnet
>   qa

Now if I provide:
    string container = "ou=qa,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=pk";

it works perfectly but my requirement is to support for both OU 
and when I try:

```
string container = "ou=dotnet,ou=qa,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=pk";
```

I get error: `there is no such object on the server.`

Can someone help me how to provide multiple OU in container? If it's possible and they are not child of each other.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think `dotnet` organization unit should be child of `qa` organization unit and you user should be in `dotnet` OU to be able to use your provided container. 
Or simply try to change container to following to support your current hierarchy.

```
string container = "ou=qa,ou=dotnet,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=pk";
```

In other words you need to bubble up in path. If you acc user in path it will look like this:

```
string container = "cn=user,ou=qa,ou=dotnet,dc=mydomain,dc=com,dc=pk";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a straightforward solution. So, I have simply created two different `PrincipalContext` objects, one for each `OU` , and then searched in both.